# If $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{7 \times 7}, \operatorname{rank}(A) = 4, \operatorname{rank}(B) = 5$, what's range of $ \operatorname{rank}(AB)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I know that the upper bound is $\min(\operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B))$, but how do I obtain the lower bound?

Comment: Hint: look at the fact that $\operatorname{nullity}(AB) \le \operatorname{nullity}(A) + \operatorname{nullity}(B)$ and see if you can derive some consequence for the rank of $AB$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Is the idea $\operatorname{nullity}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(A) = 7 \implies \operatorname{nullity}(A) = 3$ $\operatorname{nullity}(B) + \operatorname{rank}(B) = 7 \implies \operatorname{nullity}(B) = 2$. So  $\operatorname{nullity}(AB) \leq 7$. Then $\operatorname{nullity}(AB) + \operatorname{rank}(AB) = 7 \implies \min(rank(AB)) = 0$?

Comment: Well, I'd say the conclusion in the second sentence should be $\operatorname{nullity}(AB) \le 5$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oops yes you're right, so $\min(rank(AB)) = 2$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Is there an approach without using the nullity inequality theorem in your first comment? I didn't know that inequality until you mentioned it.